# When using auto layout I am not getting correct response after one complete rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have been using auto layout feature with storyboard .Now i simply added in view controller and added width and height constraints to be 300 and 200 respectively,thereafter I added horizontal and vertical alignment contraint .All works well in one rotation i.e portrait,landscape,upside down and upside up but as soon as the rotation completes the response changes .i am attaching the screenshot for reference.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Its Seems you are testing with Simulator , Please try same scenario with Device . May be problem is occurring in simulator only  .